# When I Auto run application does not play sound

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

My raspberry pi python project play a wave sound by pressing a button. In this case, no problem.

But When I Auto run application does not play sound.

I use headphone jack in my project.

Comment: Can you please add your source code.  Also which OS are you running?  And what *exactly* do you mean by "Auto run application"?  There are numerous ways in which a program can be "auto run", and it would help if we knew how.

Comment: thanks . I've run my program in raspberry pi and auto run my code in 'crontab'

Comment: while True:
    print('listening to server...')
    s.listen(1)
    conn,addr=s.accept()
    log(addr)
    print ('connect by',addr)
    timee()
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    if data==('red'):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        drum=pygame.mixer.Sound('red.wav')
        drum.play()
        conn.send(data)
        print ('recieved red alarm!')